# How to design a basic schema in Document db(NoSQL)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I have a question how to validate basic JSON fields in document. I mean suppose one field required or not, I mean basically fields validation.

I know Document DB is schema less (NOSQL) but in Mongodb there is one option is there that is why i am asking.

For example in Mongodb we have option called is below code once.
**"name": { type: String, required: true, unique: true } or
 { versionKey: false },{strict: false});**

This kind of schema validation in there in Document Db?

Answer (score 3):

DocumentDB doesn't have the notion of *required properties.* That will be up to your app to enforce.

DocumentDB does have pre-triggers you can make use of (e.g. a trigger that runs a stored procedure prior to performing an insert). In this scenario, you could validate fields within a stored procedure, and reject inserts that don't contain required properties in a given document type, within your collection.