# Alternative to schema validation in AWS DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I am moving my database in MongoDB to AWS DocumentDB. I am using `mongodb-driver` (version 3.6.4) in Java to write and read the data, as well as to configure the collections I use. In particular, I have a schema validation (written as a JSON Schema) which seems not to be compatible with AWS DocumentDB.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) the documentation says that `$jsonSchema` is not supported, but I have not seen any explicit assertion about document validation in general.

Is it really unsopported? Is there any alternative (besides doing it in the Java code)?

Comment: An alternative is provided on the below link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510903/how-to-design-a-basic-schema-in-document-dbnosql

Comment: @smthakur19 your comment is for Azure and not AWS

Comment: @Yuki the question is about having MongoDB schema-validator in AWS DocumentDB. I have included AWS documentation link for the same reference. Let me know for further inputs.

Comment: for anyone else looking, ther does NOT seem to be any info on AWS DocumentDb in the link from smthakur19. Unless I am totally blind. There seems no such thing as a pre-trigger in AWS DocumentDb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by smthakur19 in a comment above and as I expected, DocumentDB does not have the notion of required properties. However, it does have pre-triggers (e.g. one that runs a stored procedure prior to performing an insert). So it is possible to validate fields within a stored procedure and reject inserts that do not contain required properties in a given document type.

Answer (score -1):

AWS DocumentDB now supports [schema validations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/json-schema-validation.html) and operator $jsonSchema.

To create a collection with schema validations, you can use command (this is an example for aws documentation):

```
db.createCollection("employees", {
   "validator": {
      "$jsonSchema": {
         "bsonType": "object",
         "title": "employee validation",
         "required": [ "name", "employeeId"],
         "properties": {
            "name": {
                  "bsonType": "object",
                  "properties": {
                     "firstName": {
                        "bsonType": ["string"]
                     },
                     "lastName": {
                        "bsonType": ["string"]
                     }
                  },
                  "additionalProperties" : false 
            },
            "employeeId": {
               "bsonType": "string",
               "description": "Unique Identifier for employee"
            },
             "salary": {
               "bsonType": "double"
            },
            "age": {
               "bsonType": "number"
            }
         },
         "additionalProperties" : true 
      }
   },
   "validationLevel": "strict", "validationAction": "error"
} )
```

and query documents as per schema document using $jsonSchema:

```
db.employees.find({ 
       $jsonSchema: { required: ["age"] } })
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)